# Should i aggregate to merge two collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am a newbie in MongoDB and NoSQL, I am doing a simple app with 2 collection **tasks_list** and **user**, the structure like this

**tasks_list**

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61c03dfb47370c024193afde"),
    "name" : "complete unit 2",
    "createBy" : ObjectId("61c03f6b47370c024193afe0")
}
```

**users**

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61c03f6b47370c024193afe0"),
    "name" : "admin",
    "image" : "img_default.jpg"
}
```

I want to get the document of **task_list**, so I think I should be call find() 2 collection **tasks_list**, **users** or using aggregate to join collection and use find() in **tasks_list**. What is the right way?

Comment: You can do an aggregation `$lookup` to join the two collections.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to get `tasks_list` with `createBy` populated with user information? Or you already have user information, and you want to get `tasks_list` documents that are being created by that user?

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic i want to get tasks_list with user info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aggregate()` query:

```js
db.tasks_list.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "createBy",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "createBy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "createBy": {
        "$first": "$createBy"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OGM6pc8a0px)

If you are using Mongoose, you can use `populate()` method:

```js
TaskLists.find().populate('createBy');
```